# How to search a documentpanel from the itemssource of docklayoutmanager

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I have current code at the moment:

Shell:

```
<dxd:DockLayoutManager x:Name="dockLayoutManager" ActiveDockItem="{Binding ActiveSelectedView, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding DockItemsSource, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
```

This itemssource is binded to a property DockItemsSource:

```
public IEnumerable DockItemsSource { get; set; }
```

And I have a property ActiveSelectedView that should return a documentpanel:

```
private DocumentPanel _activeSelectedView;
    public DocumentPanel ActiveSelectedView
    {
        get { return _activeSelectedView; }
        set
        {
            _activeSelectedView = value;

            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(this, x => x.ActiveSelectedView);

        }

    }
```

My question to u guys is, how do I search for a documentpanel using the itemssource from my docklayoutmanager? Im using MVVM pattern.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

To activate the dock panel in MVVM manner you should bind the [DocumentPanel.IsActive](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingBaseLayoutItem_IsActivetopic) property to corresponding boolean property of your ViewModel. And you should not bind the [DockLayoutManager.ActiveDockItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ActiveDockItemtopic) property at all.

```
<Style TargetType="dxd:DocumentPanel">
    ...
    <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Please refer the following example for more details: [How to activate panel via VewModel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E3976)